# how to release a panel for using after usercontrolget Visibility.Collapsed

Tags: wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I created a userControl which has a progressbar label and textblock. (this works great) 
i have it in a panel that has also listbox.

i bind it with few property changed and one of them is Visibility.
everytime that i need to load a long list i show this usercontrol so the user will know that there is something in progress and when ist over i get the list and the userControl collapsed(=Visibility).so far so good but my problem is that this all panel and only this one looks enable but i cant do anything. no slectedItem, no scrolling nothing the rest panels and controls working fine.
i think that its the usercontrol still holding the panel although i send Visibility.Collapsed but i dont know what to do.

hope to get an answer for this problem im sure its something that ive missed or didnt pay much attention.

if u need the codes let me know.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've fix it. Just had to put the my usercontrol in new grid.

```
<Grid Height="210" Width="410" Visibility="{Binding ProbarWindow}">
                    <userControl:InProgressWindow ProgressValue="{Binding ProgressBarValue}" ProgressValueText="{Binding ProgressBarValueText}" Height="200" Width="400"/>
```

thats it.